# Why void return type gets ignored when set through type signature?

Tags: typescript

This does not produce any errors (type set through method signature):

```
let foo: () => void = () => {
    return 1000;
};
```

This produces an error as expected (only return type is set):

```
let foo = (): void => {
    return 1000;  // Type '1000' is not assignable to type 'void'.ts(2322)
};
```

What causes the behavior in the first example?

Comment: What version of TypeScript? This looks like a type inference issue, because the first example doesn't define a return type `() =>` so there is no type error for the `return` statement. It's the assignment to `foo` in the first that lacks inference.

Comment: in the first one you return a functino that return the result of assignong a function to void (I assume that might jsut return the function (and even more assumpious ) use void as a variable name)

Comment: Because the type of a function that returns a value is a subtype of a function that does not. But the type of a value is not a subtype of no value.

Comment: "The type of a function that returns a value is a subtype of a function that does not": [Relevant FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)